# Android Studio Gradle build issue

Tags: android, gradle

I upgraded the Eclipse ADT Plugin, and did an Export on a project, to use Gradle,
then Imported it to the latest Android Studio 0.3.2., selecting the 'build.gradle'
like they want you to.

I downloaded the very latest Gradle 1.9, but I was getting errors
that said basically "Need Gradle 1.6, found 1.9".

I got the build to the point where it complained about the "dependencies"
classpath in the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

So, how can I find what classpath it will be happy with, and another
question I have is, can I get away with removing the repositories, mavenCentral()?

Sorry, I'm new to trying to use Gradle, and it's been
very frustrating.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradle 1.9 is not officially supported yet. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/Xntuvifurjg/i6O0B4nyRwcJ

In the meantime gradle 1.8 should work.

Also the latest build tools are 0.6.+

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'll try to download it.

Comment: Sorry, I did get Gradle 1.8, and I think I had to also create a local.properties with: sdk.dir=C:/PROGRA~1/android-sdk-windows and I was able to do a build, thanks.